# How to add an extra assert after the test methods run using python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have **92** tests and I want to make sure that no silent errors occurred during the calls.
Unfortunately error handing in OpenGL is not quite good. I want to test if `glGetError()` returns other then `GL_NO_ERROR` It is enough if I test it once per `TestCase`. It would be better if I could add an assert after every test methods. (I don't want to add it manually in 92 methods)

I made an example snippet that shows a solution that is **not acceptable** since the assert is done in the `tearDownClass(cls)` method and `tearDownClass` should not do any testing logic.

**How can I add an extra assert after my tests?**

> The lines with comments show what I wan't to achieve.

```
import struct
import unittest

import ModernGL


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.ctx = ModernGL.create_standalone_context()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        error = cls.ctx.error                   # Store error in a variable
        cls.ctx.release()                       # Then release the context
        cls.assertEqual(error, 'GL_NO_ERROR')   # Check if there were errors before the release

    def test_1(self):
        ...

    def test_2(self):
        ...

    def test_3(self):
        ...            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**NOTE:**

`cls.ctx.error` is a **property** *(`glGetError()` as a string)* and the possible values are:

```
"GL_NO_ERROR"
"GL_INVALID_ENUM"
"GL_INVALID_VALUE"
"GL_INVALID_OPERATION"
"GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION"
"GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY"
"GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW"
"GL_STACK_OVERFLOW"
"GL_UNKNOWN_ERROR"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the test in the tearDown (as opposed to tearDownClass) method, as this is a regular instance method:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ctx = ModernGL.create_standalone_context()

    def tearDown(self):
        error = self.ctx.error                   # Store error in a variable
        self.ctx.release()                       # Then release the context
        self.assertEqual(error, 'GL_NO_ERROR')   # Check if there were errors before the release
```

Comment: Finally I used `tearDown()` to check for silent errors.